# onload doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a Javascript function when page finish loading. I tried the following:

```
<body  onload="alert('s')">
```

This code works on Firefox but for some reason not in chrome. Anything that I'm missing here?

I don't have anything in the page. I've just created a new webform ASPX page and put the above code in it.

Comment: It works.. Check the console for errors?

Comment: `and put the above code in it` - did you put proper HTML document tags, like `<html><body></body></html>`?

Comment: Please show a demo. Without that it's hard to tell what is the problem. It should work fine. Or is this the whole code in your page?

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome popup blocker add-on and that's the reason why I can see the alert box, it is being surplussed by the add-on.